# Using PHP DOMDocument, how do you find the maximum depth of loaded HTML?

Tags: php, domdocument

With a valid HTML document loaded using the PHP DOMDocument class:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

How can you get a figure for the maximum depth that the DOM tree reaches?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Check How do I ask a good question and What is on topic to make sure your post is in good shape. Your question is definitely not well presented. [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask [2]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to compute this would be to use [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), starting with a query of `*` and adding `/*` until the query returns no nodes:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '*';
$depth = 1;
while ($xpath->query($query)->length) {
    $depth++;
    $query .= "/*";
}
echo "maximum depth = $depth\n";
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TJTYm)

Comment: Thanks, that is very neat solution.